Creating optional dimensions in Google Data Studio report for viewers
I am creating self service report in Google Data Studio (Looker Studio) and the users of the report will only have Viewer access.  They would like more dimensions in the table than is readable. Has anyone found a way to create optional dimensions?  I imagine it would operate similar to optional metrics where the user would check boxes of the columns they would like to have added to the table.
I attempted to create a parameter for all the dimensions that i would like to have as options, and then use a multi-select dropdown control but it doesn't work.
